# Unable to Authenticate with Firebase Web Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Authentication using adroid app is working fine. But when I authenticate on web version of my app, I face the following bug in my terminal:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAncestorStateOfType' of null
    at Function.of (http://localhost:61698/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:22875:63)
    at Function.pop (http://localhost:61698/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:22846:28)
    at body._BodyState.new._validateRegisterInput (http://localhost:61698/packages/mn/Screens/Signup/components/body.dart.lib.js:1279:31)
    at _validateRegisterInput.throw (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:61698/dart_sdk.js:39038:38
    at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:61698/dart_sdk.js:38894:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleError (http://localhost:61698/dart_sdk.js:33887:48)
    at handleError (http://localhost:61698/dart_sdk.js:34451:51)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:61698/dart_sdk.js:34477:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeError] (http://localhost:61698/dart_sdk.js:34323:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:61698/dart_sdk.js:34362:31)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:61698/dart_sdk.js:39176:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:61698/dart_sdk.js:39182:13)
    at http://localhost:61698/dart_sdk.js:34689:9
```

This error occurs at this line:

```
UserCredential result = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
```

My Pubspec.yaml file libraries:

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.3
  device_info: ^2.0.0
  package_info: ^2.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.3
  another_flushbar: ^1.10.17
  flutter_svg: ^0.19.3
  image_picker: ^0.7.4
  firebase_auth_web: ^1.0.3
```

Can't figure out..

Comment: Do you have your firebase credentials set up in your index.html and do you have imported all the firebase libraries in your index.html as well? Please add your index.html file :)

Comment: Oops, I was missing a firebase auth library! ```<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>``` I added that in my index.html and everything started to work fine.

Comment: I'm happy that I could help :)